# Unix programming to copy to clipboard

Tags: excel, unix, ubuntu

Any idea if i can use a unix command to copy text from a file in unix onto my clipboard?

I can't use xclip and xsel as my company doesn't allow me to install utils.

Hence i am wondering if there is any workaround

If anybody needs a background to what i am doing here goes:

I am using an excel macro to launch putty and then send commands to putty using the excel macro. Part of this process requires me to copy text or certain text to my clipboard and paste it in an active cell in my excel sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that `xclip` or `xsel` would be useful here, unless you actually start an X application from `PuTTY`.

If your excel macros allow the capture of any command output, you could use [`Plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html), the cli tool which is included in a full PuTTY installation.  You still need to address any issues with remote access (creating and managing public/private keypairs for authentication.)

Check the [PuTTY docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was trying not to use Plink as well but i will try it now